# scripting return both males and females

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

hey guys i have a script

```
 #!/bin/bash
grep -i  $1  data2.txt  
echo "number of $1 :"
grep -c $1  data2.txt
```

but im getting both males and females since males is in females but how can i just show the male i can do it with cut can anyone help please?
im getting this result

```
./greparg.sh Male
Joel Craig Male
Sharon Kelly Female
Chris Foster Male
May Chin Female
Derek Johnson Male
Susan Beal Female
TJ Nichols Male
Val Shultz Male
Sheri Watson Female
number of Male :
5
```

Comment: It's worth knowing about the built-in reference guides. See `man grep` for the available options to `grep`, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Make this line:

```
grep -i  $1  data2.txt
```

to be

```
grep  $1  data2.txt
```

`-i` search for string ignoring case so it match **Male** and Fe**male**

if you want to use anyway "ignore case" you can change it like this to search for word:

```
 grep -iw  $1  data2.txt
```

Comment: but if i grep male it doesnt work

Comment: @RamiChalouhi, see my edited answer

Comment: be careful don't grep female, you get in trouble for that

Comment: okay thanks guys i should gre -iw it works @RomeoNinov thank you

Comment: @RamiChalouhi, if you are happy with the answer feel free to accept it :)